# Toggle only one show more / show less button on site with multiple buttons of the same id

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, toggle

When I click the "show more" button, more gallery images show and "show more" is changed to "show less". However, because I'm working with ExpressionEngine (CMS) templates and entries, the `id` is the same for every "show more" button on the page, causing other buttons to change its `innerText` value when they haven't actually been clicked. I need my code to reflect only one button being clicked.

Since I'm working in a CMS template, I'd like to only use HTML and JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
{if image:total>6}
<button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto" id="showMoreButton" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-{embed:park_url}-{park_facilities_relate:url_title}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="showLess()">SHOW MORE</button>
{/if}       

<script>
    var status = "less";
    function showLess() {
        if (status == "less") {
            document.getElementById("showMoreButton").innerText = "SHOW LESS";
            status = "more";
        } else if (status == "more") {
            document.getElementById("showMoreButton").innerText = "SHOW MORE";
            status = "less"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Results of what happens actually differ depending on where the `script` tag is placed (if I put the `script` tag below the `button` code vs if the `script` code is above the `button` code). Here is an image of what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the Button text you can use the event instead of getElementById().
To do so add `this` to your function call on button.

```
onclick=”showLess(this)”
```

This way you can get all the attributes of just the button you actually clicked. In the script it could look like:

```
function showLess(event) {      
   if (event.innerText == "SHOW MORE") {
        event.innerText = "SHOW LESS";
    } else if (event.innerText == "SHOW LESS") {
        event.innerText = "SHOW MORE";
    }
}
```

Don’t know anything about the actually showing of the gallery so can’t help with that but this way atleast the button works.

Comment: this is what I needed, but it looks like if you "show more" for both buttons, only one changes to "show less" thoughts @isac-larsson?

Comment: It’s because of the status variable. When you click the first button the status goes to ”more”. So when you click the second button you directly jump to the else if statement.

Comment: I edited the if statement in my post. That should work.

Comment: That was it. So it was just adding the two ='s... awesome. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

so what you could do is use the .id within your function.

```
var status = "less";
function showLess() {
    if (status == "less") {
      document.getElementById("showMoreButton").id = "showLessButton";
        document.getElementById("showMoreButton").innerText = "SHOW LESS";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
      document.getElementById("showLessButton").id = "showMoreButton";
        document.getElementById("showMoreButton").innerText = "SHOW MORE";
        status = "less"
    }
}
```

I think I have the logic the right way around but its worth thinking about. all its going to do is change the ID of the element, so it stays a a unique id and therefor you can control it better in one state rather than trying to make it to something when its one way than the other